# replacment for sed "z"- line parsing

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have text file:

```
# How often update data
period=30
#For Location
location=London.uk
```

I want print on stdout:

`London.uk`

When i use `sed  s/".*location="/""/ "$file_name"`

It work correct. But without option `-z` I have following message:

`# How often update data period=30 #For Location London.uk`

How print `location` without `-z` ?

Comment: What's the `-z` option doing?

Answer (score 1):

Try following `sed`

```
sed -n 's/^location=//p' "$file_name"
```

---

I would have preferred using `grep`

```
grep -oP '^location=\K.*' "$file_name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl as well for same:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/^location=(.*)/)' your_file
```

If you insist on sed then you can go with:

```
sed -n 's/^location=\(.*\)/\1/p' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `-z` option is, my man page doesn't know about it. But reading from your description, it's the same as the `-n` option, i.e. not printing the read lines. If you want to have a solution without `-n`, you can try

```
sed '/^location/!d; s/^location=//' "$file_name"
```

That deletes all lines that do not start with `location` and then in the line that starts with `location`, `location=` is removed.

Remains the question why you wouldn't want to use the `-n` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to try `awk`

```
awk -F= '/^location/ {print $2}' "$file_name"
London.uk
```